# GTK 3.0 - How to add a theme icon in a treeview column

Tags: c, gtk3, gnome-3

In GTK 3, how do we add a theme's icon to a tree view's column? In my following snippets, I'm trying to add a Gnome delete icon to the third column in a tree view.

I set up the third tree-view column as follows:

```c
GtkCellRenderer *rendererDelete;
GtkTreeViewColumn *columnDelete;
rendererDelete = gtk_cell_renderer_pixbuf_new();
columnDelete = gtk_tree_view_column_new_with_attributes("Delete",
    rendererDelete,
    "gicon",
    DELETE_ICON,
    NULL);
```

I attempt to retrieve the Gnome "delete" icon as follows:

```c
GdkPixbuf * delete_icon =  gtk_icon_theme_load_icon(
    gtk_icon_theme_get_default(),
    "edit-delete", /* This parameter is obviously incorrect; what is the correct value? */
    GTK_ICON_SIZE_BUTTON,
    GTK_ICON_LOOKUP_USE_BUILTIN,
    NULL);
```

I then append the entire record to the list store.

```c
gtk_list_store_set(list_store, &iter,
    ACCOUNT_NUMBER, local_account->number,
    DESCRIPTION, local_account->description,
    DELETE_ICON, delete_icon,
    FALSE,
    -1);
```

Answer (score 0):

The character string  `edit-delete` was correct. The possible character strings are the file names in `/usr/share/icons/gnome/16x16/actions`. For example, to use the icon for `gtk-underline.png`, use the character string `gtk-underline`.

My error was not instantiating the `GtkListStore` correctly.

```c
GtkListStore *list_store = gtk_list_store_new(
  N_COLUMNS,
  G_TYPE_STRING,
  G_TYPE_STRING,
  GDK_TYPE_PIXBUF);
```

In the last position I mistakenly used an incorrect data type.